# Как убрать пробелы между span

Tags: html

Нужно сделать так, чтобы между `span` не было пробелов, а был лишь `:`.

HTML:

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <span class="days time-font">00</span>
  <span class="hours time-font">00</span>:
  <span class="minutes time-font">00</span>:
  <span class="seconds time-font">00</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отступы между элементами с inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-inline-block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так вы их сами поставили. Ваши переходы на новую строку между `span`-ами переводятся в знак пробела.

```html
<div id="countdown">
  <span class="days time-font">00</span>
  <span class="hours time-font">00</span>:<!--
--><span class="minutes time-font">00</span>:<!--
--><span class="seconds time-font">00</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `inline-block` рендерится браузером как буква. Расстояние, которое вы видите между `inline-block` и соседними "буквами"  –  обычный межбуквенный интервал или, если брать термин из типографики, [трекинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Трекинг не является фиксированным значением и меняется в различных семействах шрифтов, а также зависит от размера шрифта. Из-за этого мы не можем использовать для решения этой проблемы фиксированные значения в свойствах `word-spacing`, `margin` и т.д.

Эффективно убрать **отступы у `inline-block`** можно несколькими способами:

#### Вариант 1

В разметке убираем переносы для кнопок.

```
<main>
  <button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

#### Вариант 2

На родителя ставим font-size: 0; а уже к button задаем нужный размер шрифта.

```
main {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

#### Вариант 3

Можно закомментировать конец и начало строки.

```
<main><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
--></main>
```