# Отступы между инлайновыми элементами

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Откуда берутся отступы между элементами с `display: inline-block;` и как их убрать? Отступы нигде не фиксируются:

[image: Отступы]

Comment: Попробуйте указать код всех кнопок в одну строчку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Расстояние, которое вы видите между `inline` или `inline-block` и соседними словами – обычный пробел.

Пробел не является фиксированным значением и меняется в различных семействах шрифтов, а также зависит от размера шрифта. Из-за этого мы не можем использовать для решения этой проблемы фиксированные значения в свойствах `word-spacing`, `margin` и т.д.

Эффективно убрать **отступы у `inline-block`** можно несколькими способами (от актуального до устаревшего):

#### Вариант 1

Использовать `white-space: nowrap`:

```
main {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<main>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

#### Вариант 2

Использовать `display: flex`:

```
main {
    display: flex;
}

<main>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

#### Вариант 3

На родителя ставим `font-size: 0`, а уже к `button` задаём нужный размер шрифта.

```
main {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

#### Вариант 4

В разметке убираем переносы для кнопок.

```
<main>
  <button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

#### Вариант 5

Можно закомментировать конец и начало строки:

```
<main><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
--></main>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Вариант 1:**

*margin-left (отрицательный)* — свойство, с помощью которого можно сдвинуть пункты влево, как бы друг на друга, "избавившись" так сказать от ненавистного пробела между них.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li + li {
  margin-left: -.36em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 2:**

*font-size* — свойство, задающее размер шрифта, с помощью которого нашему пробелу (символу) можно выставить размер шрифта, равный нулю, и тем самым сделать его настолько маленьким, что его попусту не будет видно.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  /* Выставляем родителю значение в ноль */
  font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
  /* Возвращаем в нормальное состояние у потомков */
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 3:**

*letter-spacing* — свойство, определяющее интервал между символами. По умолчанию (normal) задаёт обычный интервал, исходя из размера и типа шрифта.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  /* Выставляем родителю значение -.36em */
  letter-spacing: -.36em;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
  /* Возвращаем в нормальное состояние у потомков */
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 4:**

*word-spacing* — свойство, определяющее интервал между словами. По умолчанию так же, как и letter-spacing, задаёт его в зависимости от размера и типа шрифта.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  /* Выставляем родителю значение -.36em */
  word-spacing: -.36em;
  /* Лекарство для webkit */
  display: table;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
  /* Возвращаем в нормальное состояние у потомков */
  word-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 5:**

Прижать элементы друг к другу, т.е. вплотную, тег к тегу, и таким образом убрать межссловный интервал.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li><li>Пункт 2</li><li>Пункт 3</li><li>Пункт 4</li><li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 6:**

Поставить комментарии между элементами, тем самым убрав между ними отступы.

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li><!--
  --><li>Пункт 2</li><!--
  --><li>Пункт 3</li><!--
  --><li>Пункт 4</li><!--
  --><li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 7:**

Не указывать закрывающие теги для li

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1
  <li>Пункт 2
  <li>Пункт 3
  <li>Пункт 4
  <li>Пункт 5
</ul>
```

**Вариант 8:**

Переместить закрывающую скобку на следующую строку

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li
  ><li>Пункт 2</li
  ><li>Пункт 3</li
  ><li>Пункт 4</li
  ><li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 9:**

JS скриптом:

```js
document.сlearSpaces = function(node) {
  var childLength = node.childNodes.length;

  if( childLength === 0 ) {
    return;
  };
  
  for(var i = childLength; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    var children = node.childNodes[i - 1];
  
    var nodeType = children.nodeType,
        nodeValue = children.nodeValue;
    
    if( nodeType === 8 || ( nodeType === 3 && !/\S/.test( nodeValue ) ) ) {
      node.removeChild( children );
    }
  }
};

document.сlearSpaces(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery скриптом:

```js
$(function() {
  $.сlearSpaces = function($elements) {
    $elements.contents().each(function() {
      var nodeType = this.nodeType,
          nodeValue = this.nodeValue;

      if (nodeType === 8 || (nodeType === 3 && !/\S/.test(nodeValue))) {
        $(this).remove();
      };
    });
  };

  $.сlearSpaces($('ul'));
});
```

```css
ul {
  font: 14px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #E76D13;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Пункт 1</li>
  <li>Пункт 2</li>
  <li>Пункт 3</li>
  <li>Пункт 4</li>
  <li>Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Источник: http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html</sub>

Comment: Половина рабочий вариантов скопировано с моего ответа, а остальное - костыли.

Answer (score 4):

Помогло:

> Попробуйте указать код всех кнопок в одну строчку

Comment: У меня тоже такое было когда-то. По этому перешёл на использование `display: flex`

Comment: @Yuri мне нравятся, как все сейчас разучились верстать и переходят на flexbox, вот только подумали ли вы о поддержке старых браузеров?

Comment: @Vadizar,а чего о них думать? Большинство сайтов больших компаний даже перестают их поддерживать и когда заходишь на их сайты со старых браузеров, они пишут, что бы мы обновили его

Answer (score 3):

Более корректный ответ состоит в том, чтобы просто не использовать элементы с `display: inline-block` для создания вашей разметки.

Пора использовать более современные CSS-модули: Flexbox для одномерных разметок и CSS Grid для 2D.

---

Решение данной задачи через Flexbox:

```css
.number-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>
```

Через CSS Grid (более предпочтительно в данном случае):

```css
.number-buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

button:last-child {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="number-buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
  <button>0</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Для названия CSS-модулей не нужно использовать внутристочное формативание. Это вытекает из [ответа на FAQ-вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1338/220571), секция "Названия IDE, библиотек, плагинов, инструментов", так как CSS-модули концептуально схожи с библиотеками кода.

Comment: Вы наверное перепутали топики. Здесь нет никакой моей активности ни в вопросах, ни в ответах, ни в комментариях

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Ну версия №2 с помещением Flexbox и CSS Grid во внутристрочное форматирование была ваша (которую я откатил). Если бы вашей активности не было, то вы бы не увидели уведомление об этом сообщении.

Comment: теперь понял, что вы имели ввиду