# Как растянуть высоту <div> тегом <a>?

Tags: html, css

Почему не меняется высота `div`, когда в нем есть ссылка? Сама ссылка начинается в `div` и из-за своей высоты выходит за его пределы.

```css
.list-menu a:link, a:visited {   
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .list-menu a:hover,  a:active { 
  background-color: red; 
 }

#navigation {
  clear:both;  
  padding-top:10px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

.list-menu {
  width:90%; 
  float:left; 
  display:inline-block; 
}

.search {
  width:10%;
  float:left; 
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="list-menu"> 
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <a href="#">Регистрация</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search"> 
    <form action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск">
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.list-menu a:link, a:visited` - это так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сразу несколько ошибок.

Во-первых, вы не очистили поток после float-элементов. Чтобы очистить поток, примените следующие стили:

```
 #navigation {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Или же:

```
 #navigation:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
 }
```

Во-вторых, ссылкам нужно проставить свойство `display: inline-block;`, чтобы они имели высоту и могли расширять родительский блок:

```
 a {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

Полный пример:

```css
.list-menu a:link, a:visited {   
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
 .list-menu a:hover,  a:active { 
  background-color: red; 
 }

#navigation {
  clear:both;  
  padding-top:10px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid maroon;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

#navigation:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
 }

.list-menu {
  width:90%; 
  float:left; 
  display:inline-block; 
}

.search {
  width:10%;
  float:left; 
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="list-menu"> 
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <a href="#">Регистрация</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search"> 
    <form action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск">
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А разве не clear управляет потоком элементов? overflow же отображает только то, что внутри его элемента? Не пойму, как он работает. Код конечно же теперь работает как мне хотелось. Спасибо! Теперь только еще одна проблема осталась, когда ссылки в блоке между ними происходит отступ, которого нет при обычном размещении ссылок. Как его можно побороть?

Comment: пробел убрал с помощью margin-left:-5px; насколько правильно только это.

Comment: @Дмитрий пробел можно убрать через способы, перечисленные в этом вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Как-убрать-отступы-между-кнопками/610041#610041

Comment: Спасибо! Насчет overflow разобрался, нашел этот же пример на w3.

Answer (score 1):

добавьте для ссылки `display:block;`

Comment: не помогает, ссылки в список выстраиваются и вытягиваются по ширине всего "list-menu"