# Перенос из-за inline-block, CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, inline

`wrapper` имеет `width: 980px;`

Последний блок переносится на новую строку.

footer и clearfix не предлагайте, пожалуйста.

Много серфил, но не нашел решения.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inline {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.sidebar-1,
.sidebar-2,
.sidebar-3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.sidebar-2 {
  width: 25%;
}

.sidebar-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inline sidebar-1">
    <div class="inner-sidebar-1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inline sidebar-2">
    <div class="inner-sidebar-2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inline sidebar-3">
    <div class="inner-sidebar-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отступы между элементами с inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-inline-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inline {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Замени на

```
.content{
   font-size: 0px;
}
```