# Отступы между элементами с нулевым margin

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, откуда берутся отступы между пунктами меню?

```css
.menu {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.section_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  line-height: 10vh;
  padding: 0px 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт1</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт2</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт3</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отступы между элементами с inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-inline-block)

Comment: Сделал варант 3й из ссылки выше:закомментировал пробелы. Благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более корректно просто использовать современные модули CSS, к примеру flexbox, который лишён недостатков `inline-block`.

```css
.menu {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 10vh;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section_menu {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  line-height: 10vh;
  padding: 0px 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт1</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт2</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт3</div>
  <div class='section_menu'>Пункт4</div>
</div>
```